# Compare the date to the current date

Tags: android-studio

I want to compare the current date with the specified date. This is necessary in order that every day the content of TextView should change, for example: the time of sunrise.

Comment: The time that takes to type your name is longer than the time it takes to find an example of date comparison in Google...

Comment: @alfasin I am newbie. Yet I was looking. The fact that I did not fit. Could not properly understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

If your date is in ***31/12/2014*** format.

```
String my_date = "31/12/2014"
```

Then you need to convert it into **SimpleDateFormat**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(my_date);
if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
    your_date_is_out_dated = true;
}
else{
    your_date_is_outdated = false;
}
```

or

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(my_date);
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > strDate.getTime()) {
    your_date_is_out_dated = true;
}
else{
    your_date_is_outdated = false;
}
```

Comment: sdf.parse(my_date) this place is stressed with an error: unhandled exception java.text.parseexception... ((

Comment: can you check the package which was imported in your code.